# dc.js accessing a chart other that it's own in postRender

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have 2 charts on a page (A and B) and wish for some custom behavior to be added to chart B when a brush filter on chart A is performed.

I thought I could achieve this by doing something like;

```
charta.on('postRender', function(){

...

d3.selectAll('#chartb svg')
.data(nested, function(d){ return d.key})
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", "aclass")... more code....
```

But this `#chartb` selector doesn't seem to work - when I inspect the DOM it has appended the `<g>` attributes to the `<html>` element and not the `svg` element I wanted to append to.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just adding stuff to the other chart, something like this should be possible.  I don't think you will be able to select the generated items of the other chart and then apply a d3 join to it, because it is already joined.

I believe the problem with the code above is that `d3.select` is what you use to choose the context for a join, and `d3.selectAll` is what you use to actually make the data join.  See

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

So your code is trying to join to the chart and svg elements, which would have the effect you are describing.  Instead you'll want to `d3.select` the `svg` and then `d3.selectAll` the elements you want to add - even though they don't exist yet!  Yes, it's kind of a mind-bender; take a look at the above and the linked articles to get a better idea of it.

Note: [there are dc convenience methods on the chart object](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#selectselector) which will execute the selects in the right context.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in the end by replacing the .enter() with repeated calls to datum() instead. A bit of a hack, but it works; If anyone can suggest a more d3ish way of acheiving this, I would be very grateful.

```
var svg = chart.svg();

nested.forEach(function(withValues) {

                            _(withValues.values).filter(function(d){return d.value < threshold}).forEach(function(timesMatchingThreshold){
                                svg.datum(timesMatchingThreshold)
                                    .append("rect")
                                    .style("opacity", 0.6)
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 30 + ", " + (-30) + ")")
                                    .attr("class", "belowThreshold")
                                    .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.date)})
                                    .attr("y", function(d) {return 200 -  y(d.value)})
                                    .attr("width", 3)
                                    .attr("height", function(d) {return y(d.value)});

                            });
```